# Updated Windows, now keep getting logged off. Can log in in Safe Mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, chkdsk, sfc

So I finally got around to installing the latest update to Windows this morning, and am getting logged out fairly shortly after logging in, depending on what I do. So I'm going to list all the symptoms and what I've tried to see if anyone knows what's wrong.

So first of all, what happens is after logging in and clicking on something, the screen turns black, and then several seconds later I'm back at the log in screen. So for example, I tried to bring up the command prompt at one point, that causes it. I have a few programs that load on startup that I never bothered to disable, just some social gaming crap that got installed with my AMD drivers. They'll pop up with a log in prompt, if I close those the same happens. However, I can open Chrome and that doesn't cause a restart.

Some other things possible related things that I noticed were happening prior to the update that could be related: my icons on my desktop kept resizing themselves. Every time I'd restart they'd be enormous, then I'd reset them, and at some point they'd be huge again. Not sure when that would happen since I almost always have multiple windows open, but my guess would be after going to sleep they would resize themselves. Also, I couldn't delete files. I'd drag stuff to the recycle bin and nothing would happen. Trying to delete someone in Windows Explorer would cause that it to crash. So obviously something was messed up, but I just sort of ignored it since it didn't affect my day to day life. This update seems to have fixed the icon size issue, but I am still unable to delete files and send them to the recycle bin.

So here's what I've tried to do so far to fix it. I'm typing this from Safe Mode, where everything seems to be normal (although the recycle bin still doesn't work). I tried to do a system refresh while saving all my files by shift restarting from the log in screen and choosing that option when it rebooted. It restarted fine and I got to that screen. However, when I tried to start that process, the screen went black again and seemed to hang, and so I ended up doing a hard reboot.

I also had issues with that. Unless I unplugged the computer, held down the power button for 30 seconds to let the capacitors discharge or whatever that does, and then plug it back in, I was unable to reboot. The computer would turn back on, but nothing would display on the monitor, not even the splash screen.

The next thing I tried was to run chkdsk by restarting into the command prompt to see if that would fix something. That ran, went through five steps, reported no errors, then exit with Failed to Transfer Logged Messages to the Event Log with Status 50. I ran that twice, the first time with /r /f and the second time with /r /f /v after googling to see what Status 50 meant and that as a suggestion. Same result both times.

I also attempted to run sfc /scannow afrer running chkdsk. When I tried to run that, I got through the verification phase, then was told Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service.

So that's pretty much where I am now. Rebooted regularly, still getting the same logging out behavior. Rebooted into safe mode and everything seems OK, that's where I'm typing this from now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So there was thing I hadn't tried, which was run the commands from the command prompt in safe mode. So I was able to run sfc /scannow in safe mode and it did find a corrupt file and repaired it, mscormmc.dll. That didn't fix the log in issue, although it did fix the inability to use the recycle bin. However, this time when I attempted to reset my system, instead of simply going to a black screen like my previous couple of attempts, it actual went through all the steps like it should have and now I'm back up and running